# Shibboleth 4 IDP: assign attribute resolver to specific flow

Tags: shibboleth, idp

I have two login flows. I want flow1 to only use the standard `attribute-resolver.xml` file and flow2 to only use `attribute-resolver-ldap.xml`. Where do I tell the IDP what resolver it should use for a flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to Shibboleth's main developer Scott Cantor, and he wrote that such behaviour is not possible with Shibboleth (at least with version 4.0.1). However, I solved my core problem using an entirely alternative way. Here's the link: [Shibboleth 4 IDP: Query two different login sources with the Password flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65234929/shibboleth-4-idp-query-two-different-login-sources-with-the-password-flow)