# Shibboleth 4 IDP: Query two different login sources with the Password flow

Tags: shibboleth, idp

I have two login sources (an Active Directory and a local MySQL Database) that each contain different users. I want to configure the Password flow in this way:

- query the AD first
- if this succeeds, the user gets logged in
- if it fails, query the local database and log the user in if this succeeds
- else, authentication fails

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution I found:

inside the file `conf/authn/password-authn-config.xml` put the following lines or replace if they already exist:

```xml
<import resource="jaas-authn-config.xml"/>

<!-- Ordered list of CredentialValidators to apply to a request. -->
<util:list id="shibboleth.authn.Password.Validators">
    <ref bean="shibboleth.JAASValidator"/>
</util:list>
```

Comment out any other resources that you don't need, such as `ldap-authn-config.xml` or `krb5-authn-config.xml`.

In my case, I want the login to succeed if either of my login sources return 'okay'. Therefore you need this line:

```xml
<!-- Controls whether all validators in the above bean have to succeed, or just one. -->
<util:constant id="shibboleth.authn.Password.RequireAll" static-field="java.lang.Boolean.FALSE"/>
```

If you want all login sources to succeed, just replace 'FALSE' with 'TRUE'.

Next, put the following inside `conf/authn/jaas-authn-config.xml`:

```xml
<!-- Specify your JAAS config. -->
<bean id="JAASConfig" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource" c:path="%{idp.home}/conf/authn/jaas.config" />
    
<util:property-path id="shibboleth.authn.JAAS.JAASConfigURI" path="JAASConfig.URI" />
    
<!-- Specify the application name(s) in the JAAS config. -->
<util:list id="shibboleth.authn.JAAS.LoginConfigNames">
    <value>ShibUserPassAuthLDAP</value>
    <value>ShibUserPassAuthJAAS</value>
</util:list>
```

Now open `conf/authn/jaas.config` and write this:

```
ShibUserPassAuthJAAS {
    relationalLogin.DBLogin required debug=true
    dbDriver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    userTable="login"
    userColumn="email"
    passColumn="password"
    dbURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login"
    dbUser="your_db_user"
    dbPassword="your_db_password"
    hashAlgorithm="SHA2" // or what u need
    saltColumn="salt" // leave empty if you don't need this
    errorMessage="Invalid password"
    where="status < 9999"; // remove if you don't need this
};

ShibUserPassAuthLDAP {
    org.ldaptive.jaas.LdapLoginModule required
    ldapUrl="ldap://localhost:10389" // your active directory url
    useStartTLS="true"
    baseDn="OU=example,OU=example,DC=example,DC=org" // change this to whatever you need
    bindDn="CN=shibboleth,OU=example,DC=example,DC=local" // change this to whatever you need
    bindCredential="your_ad_password"
    userFilter="(sAMAccountName={user})"
    credentialConfig="{trustCertificates=file:/opt/shibboleth-idp/credentials/ldap.pem}";
};
```

`relationalLogin.DBLogin` is a java class I use to actually check the credentials. You can download it from here: [download the jar](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j7lVAmJfRPPZkBB6R8jL5yWLfg0Long-/view?usp=sharing)

Just put it in this directory on your idp: `{shibboleth_root}/edit-webapp/WEB-INF/lib/`

Now make sure you configured the password flow correctly in `conf/authn/general_authn.xml`:

```xml
<bean id="authn/Password" parent="shibboleth.AuthenticationFlow"
              p:passiveAuthenticationSupported="true"
              p:forcedAuthenticationSupported="true"/>
```

And to enable the Password flow change this line in `idp.properties`:

```
idp.authn.flows=
```

to this:

```
idp.authn.flows=Password
```

After you completed these steps, don't forget to restart jetty for the changes to take effect.

### Explanation

The two entries called `ShibUserPassAuthLDAP` and `ShibUserPassAuthJAAS` in `jaas-authn-config.xml` are where the magic happens: the password flow will try to validate the credentials using those two configurations you provided. It will try the first one and finish authentication if it succeeds, or try the second configuration if the first fails.

Comment: I have a hunch that the jar you link to is from the robertogallea/jaas_relational_login project on GitHub: https://github.com/robertogallea/jaas_relational_login

Just pointing that out in case anyone wants to build from source.